# Customization of Apex:vote component

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, ui

Is there any way to customize the design of apex:vote component? In the docs there seems to be no other attribute to customize it, what I could think of though is to hack it through javascript but it wouldn't seem efficient.

Or, do you have any idea how that apex:vote component works? So maybe I could just replicate its functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar with the [Google Chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), but you'll be able to customize the component with CSS if you inspect the element with these tools.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't the visual force code has those elements encapsulated in <apex:vote> component? Or should I really resort to javascript and manually edit it there by class/id(whichever works) name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the HTML generated by Salesforce using the apex:vote component:

```
<div class="voteContainer">
   <div>
      <div class="voteButtons">
         <div class="votedButton votedUpButton" id="voteButtonsStyle">
            <div class="voteUp"><span class="voteButtonText">promoted</span></div>
            <div class="voteDown"><span class="voteButtonText">demoted</span></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="voteStatusBlock">
         <div class="score">10</div>
         <div class="label">Points</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Salesforce allows you add CSS to your visualforce page as you can see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_custom.htm).

So you can customize the component, for example, to increase the score font size using:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .voteContainer .voteStatusBlock .score{
        font-size: 22px;
   }
</style>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to change the text of 'promoted' or 'demoted':

```
.voteButtonText{
    display: none;
}
.voteUp:after{
    content: 'Test promoted';
}
.voteDown:after{
    content: 'Test demoted';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! what about if for example we want to change the text of Promoted and Demoted?

Comment: You could do it with Javascript but you can do it with CSS too as you can see in my updated answer.